# How to bind a method that returns std::shared_ptr< uint8_t > with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, python-imaging-library, shared-ptr, pybind11

From **C++** via **pybind11** to **Python** project I've met with an issue and I don't know how to proceed.

### Intro, "Holder classes are only supported for custom types"

There is an abstract C++ class `Page` with a pure virtual method `Render` that returns a heap buffer guarded by a smart pointer:

```cpp
class Page {
    // ...
    std::shared_ptr< uint8_t > Render( /*...*/ ) const = 0;
    // ...
};
```

To solve the abstraction - I added a trampoline:

```cpp
class PageTr : public Page {
    //...
    std::shared_ptr< uint8_t >  Render( /*...*/ ) const override {
        PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE( std::shared_ptr< uint8_t >, Page, Render,
            /*...*/ );
    }
    //...
};
```

The c++17 compiler (from within `pybind11.h`) complained with: **Holder classes are only supported for custom types**.

After a deep study (based on discussion on binding `std::shared_ptr<void>`) I realized that I must define an **opaque** custom type like:

```cpp
using UInt8_Ptr = std::shared_ptr< uint8_t >;
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE( UInt8_Ptr );
```

inside appropriate `.h` file, and, in a `.cpp` file:

```cpp
py::class_< UInt8_Ptr >( m, "UInt8_Ptr" );
```

And all was fine. The binding is:

```cpp
void BindPage( py::module_& m ) {
    py::class_< Page, PageTr, std::shared_ptr< Page >> cls( m, "Page" );
    cls.def( "Render", &Page::Render, "ToDo", return_value_policy::reference )
    // ...
}
```

The code compiles but was neither checked nor used yet.

### Side Effect "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'UInt8_Ptr'"

But, after some time, at a totally *independent* place in project, an issue is raised.

I needed an access from Python to a C++ heap-allocated buffer, containing RGBA `uint8_t` image samples in an instance of this class:

```cpp
class Bitmap {
public:
    //...
    BitmapSamplesPtr GetSamples() {
        return this->m_SamplesPtr;
    }

private:
    BitmapSamplesPtr    m_SamplesPtr;
};
```

where `BitmapSamplesPtr` is defined as:

```cpp
using BitmapSamplesPtr = std::shared_ptr< uint8_t >;
```

It is bound as:

```cpp
void Bind_Bitmap( py::module_& m ) {
    py::class_< Bitmap, std::shared_ptr< Bitmap >>  cls( m, "Bitmap" );

    cls.def( "GetSamples", &Bitmap::GetSamples, "ToDo",
        py::return_value_policy::reference );
    //...
}
```

and I managed to get, within a test suite, an instance of it on Python side (as later `pageBmp`). But when I tried to create a `GIL.Image.frombuffer()` in this way:

```py
w = pageBmp.GetWidth()
h = pageBmp.GetHeight()
pilImg = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), pageBmp.GetSamples(), 'raw')
```

the Python complained with:

```
  [...]
  File "[...]\tests\test_Doc.py", line 87, in OnPageDone
    pilImg = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), pageBmp.GetSamples(), 'raw')
  File "D:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2796, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "D:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2742, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "D:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 807, in frombytes
    s = d.decode(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'UInt8_Ptr'
```

### Thinking...

Then I realized that `BitmapSamplesPtr` is treated as an alias of `UInt8_Ptr` (once it is being propagated as **opaque** through the whole project) - and it is OK.

But how to solve the PIL Image issue? Should not **un-opaque** it since abstract Page still needs it.
I am considering several scenarios/solutions:

1. numpy, ndarray
2. py::buffer_protocol
3. py::bytes

but not sure on the propper way to go. It looks to me that, the most promising way (3.) is to replace `UInt8_Ptr` with `py::bytes`. Seems for that, I'll have to wrap the bindings with lambda to return `py::bytes`.

### And here are my questions...

1. How to ensure that `std::shared_ptr< uint8_t >` exists as a `Page::Render()` return value? Or in other words, was the **opaque** type of it a correct decision?
2. If **opaque** `UInt8_Ptr` is a must, how to expose the `uint8_t*` from it on Python side? A getter method?
3. What are the **bytes-like** objects which will make `PIL.Image` happy?
4. If `py::bytes` is a solution, how the lambda function should look like?
5. Since `PIL.Image` is cappable to use a `const uint8_t*` with and without making a copy - what would be the optimal but enough secure way to go? (I would prefer a copy and decouple the ownership regardless it is not expected the bitmap-samples-buffer to be modified on Python side.)

### Edit

I made an attempt that gave me first result.
First, (according to pybind11 PDF doc *12.2.7 Memory view*) I used lambda function to expose the Bitmap samples via `memoryview` as:

```cpp
cls.def( "GetSamples",
    []( const Bitmap& bmp ) {
        const uint8_t*  bmpBuf  = bmp.GetSamples().get();
        uint32_t        height  = bmp.GetHeight();
        uint32_t        stride  = bmp.GetStride();

        return py::memoryview::from_memory( bmpBuf, height * stride );
    },
    "ToDo" );
```

But that produced another error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not `memoryview`
```

Then I investigated how to get `bytes-like` from 'memoryview' and it was unexpectedly simple - wrap with `bytes()` on Python side:

```py
pilImg = Image.frombytes( 'RGBA', ( w, h ), bytes( pageBmp.GetSamples() ), 'raw' )
```

I switched to `Image.frombytes` instead of `Image.frombuffer` since the first makes a copy which ensures that the original buffer could be freely released once we return from the test code.
Saved PIL.Image to file looks fine.

Maybe there is a better way, thus I still appreciate comments.